# Selection sort animation isn't iterating through the steps of sorting like I intended

Tags: javascript, html, selection-sort

Below, I've included the two functions which most likely contain error. The function `iterate` should pause the program for one second, clear the body of the page, then, for every index in the list `colors`, create a `div` with a unique color and height based on a list `order`. The function `selectionSort` is a common selection-sort function which, after one iteration of sorting the list `order`, should execute the function `iterate`. For some reason, this code produces the final sorted result after one second instead of pausing through every iteration of sorting to display a partially sorted line of divs. Does anyone see any glaring issues with this code? I'll also add that the sleep function itself works properly.

```
function selectionSort() {
            for (i=0; i<order.length-1; i++) {
                let minIndex = i;
                
                for (j=i+1; j<order.length; j++) {
                    if (order[j] < order[minIndex]) {
                        minIndex = j;
                    }
                }
                
                [order[i], order[minIndex]] = [order[minIndex], order[i]];
                
                iterate();
            }
        }
```

```
async function iterate() {
            await sleep(1000);
            document.body.innerHTML = "";
            for (i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
                let newDiv = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
                
                newDiv.style.backgroundColor = colors[order[i]];
                newDiv.style.height = ((order[i] * 2.4) + 36).toString() + "px";
            }
        }
```

If it helps, this is the full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Sorting Algorythm</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {background: black;}
            div {margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; display: inline-block; width: 5.5px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    <script>
        var colors = [];
        let order = [];
        
        setup();
        iterate();
        selectionSort();
        
        function setup() {
            for (i=16; i<256; i++) {
                colors.push("#BB" + i.toString(16) + i.toString(16));
            }
            
            for (i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
                order.push(i);
            }
            
            shuffle(order);
        }
        
        function selectionSort() {
            for (i=0; i<order.length-1; i++) {
                let minIndex = i;
                
                for (j=i+1; j<order.length; j++) {
                    if (order[j] < order[minIndex]) {
                        minIndex = j;
                    }
                }
                
                [order[i], order[minIndex]] = [order[minIndex], order[i]];
                
                iterate();
            }
        }
        
        async function iterate() {
            await sleep(1000);
            document.body.innerHTML = "";
            for (i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
                let newDiv = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
                
                newDiv.style.backgroundColor = colors[order[i]];
                newDiv.style.height = ((order[i] * 2.4) + 36).toString() + "px";
            }
        }
        
        function shuffle(array) {
            for (i=array.length-1; i>0; i--) {
                let j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
                [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
            }
            return array;
        }
        
        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems:

1. Every time you have `for (i = 0…`, you should be declaring `i` as a variable for that loop instead, like `for (let i = 0…`.

   By doing `i = 0` instead of `let i = 0` (or `var i = 0`), you are implicitly creating a global variable `i`, which means all the loops are accessing and updating the same `i` at the same time and screwing everything up. You want a separate `i` for each loop. This also goes for the `j` inside the nested loop in `selectionSort`.
2. Since you are calling `iterate()` inside a loop in your `selectionSort` function, and `iterate` is async, you have to `await iterate()` if you want a pause between each loop in `selectionSort`. That also means `selectionSort` needs to be async as well.

Making those two changes we get this (check your console):

```js
var colors = [];
let order = [];

setup();
iterate();
selectionSort();

function setup() {
  for (let i = 16; i < 256; i++) {
    colors.push("#BB" + i.toString(16) + i.toString(16));
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    order.push(i);
  }

  shuffle(order);
}

async function selectionSort() {
  for (let i = 0; i < order.length - 1; i++) {
    let minIndex = i;

    for (let j = i + 1; j < order.length; j++) {
      if (order[j] < order[minIndex]) {
        minIndex = j;
      }
    }

    [order[i], order[minIndex]] = [order[minIndex], order[i]];
    console.log('calling iterate', i);
    await iterate();
  }
}

async function iterate() {
  await sleep(1000);
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    let newDiv = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = colors[order[i]];
    newDiv.style.height = ((order[i] * 2.4) + 36).toString() + "px";
  }
}

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5.5px;
}
```